# Can Artifactory use SQL Server database with different database and database user names?

Tags: sql-server, artifactory

According to Jfrog documentation -[here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JCR/Microsoft+SQL+Server)

The DB name and user should be called `artifactory`.

However, this is can be parameterized in the `db.properties` file.

Since we have one SQL Server that needs to serve several `Artifactory` instances, can we create a different databases using a different SQL Server user and work with it in `Artifactory`?

Comment: Please mark the answer as an accepted if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you can use any name.

1. Use any name for the `artifactory` database [e.g. `artifactorytest`]
2. change the configuration.

> url=jdbc:sqlserver://hostname:1433;databaseName=artifactorytest;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;applicationName=Artifactory Binary Repository

Comment: Thanks, is this also true for the SQL user ? or must is be "artifactory" ? because the instructions said-  "Create user "artifactory" and set its password"